# C3js customize tooltip of scatter chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, c3.js

I created a scatter chartlike this in the JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/102/)
which is doing two dimension data analysis.

but I need to contain some **extra information** (e.g: **custom names and a extra count value**) in the chart** and **give different color for each of the plots.**

I tried to create an Array and use the tooltip library like this but i didn't reach the goal yet still.

```
    var nameArr = ['anson','jason','samson','dickson']; // Names

          tooltip: {
                format: {
                    title: function (d) { return nameArr; },  
                }
            }
```

Please see the JSfiddle code for further details, many thanks

The below is the current result and the exception exception after development

[image: Current]

[image]

Comment: can you mention how you want to show the value..

Comment: I have updated my question, i understand i might not able to get everything work as what I except above, but at least i can satisfy few requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have gone through the jsfiddle link and there were two issue with this:-

1. c3js library is old
2. c3js does not provide this functionality out of the box but you can achieve this using trick.

I have fixed both of above given issues and now it is working fine.
jsfiddle:- 
  http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/109/

code for setting the tooltip:-

```
       tooltip: {
       format: {
           title: function(x) {
               var indOfVal = engagmentArr.indexOf(x);
               return nameArr[indOfVal - 1]
           },
           name: function() {
               return engagmentArr[0];
           }
       },

   },
```